# Reducing xtick interval [Non linear data. Floats]

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, xticks

I have been working on a dataframe plot, where I have 2k values to show and its indexes. However, when I try to plot them, obviously, matplotlib tries to squeeze all the index labels in the axis, making it impossible to read. It looks like this:
[image: Plot image]

I have tried to increase figsize, but there are just too much xticks. Since the data is not linear (there are maybe 900 values between 0 and 1, 600 values between 1-100 and the rest >100), I cannot just re-arange the xticks with `np.arange()`, since the data loses correlation (there are 2k bars, but the last index is 1534.34). If I try `xticks=np.arange(0, max1, max1/20)` to get 20 ticks evenly spaced, I get this result:
[image: Xticks plot]

Which obviously, is not true, since like I said, the max index is 1534.34, so that the last tick should be at the very end of the horizontal axis. Also, as as said, the first 900 values are between 0 and 1, and this is not true in the plot.

I don't know if I've been clear enough or this question is adequate, but this is my first question and I have tried to. So don't be too harsh please. However all criticism is welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always provide a complete [mre] with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, only plot images are okay. Provide data with [How to provide a reproducible copy of your DataFrame using `df.head(30).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52413246/7758804), then **[edit] your question**, and paste the clipboard into a code block.

Comment: Show us your code (the relevant parts, I mean…)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Guys, it was a conceptual thing, so I tought no code was necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MaxNLocator(interval))` to set my ticks on the x axis after defining the interval as some integer. See documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html). I think this relies on calling the graph in a form such as:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,2))
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
```

Comment: Thank you, I didnt know about locators. This is what I need.